# Install psycopg2 on Windows 8.1

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, windows-8.1, psycopg2

I want to install psycopg2 on Windows 8.1 x64 computer and I'm using python 2.7.6 from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). As I launch the installer as administrator, I got this error,

[image]

I press confirm and next button, but I can't choose or type my python directory.

I have seen this post after I got those problem, [Psycopg installation on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171334/psycopg-installation-on-windows), but it seems that that is a different case as mine.

How to successfully install psycopg2 on Windows 8.1 x64 computer？

Comment: Did you install the x64 build of Python 2.7, and is this the x64 psycopg2? (or, alternately, are both 32-bit?)

Comment: @CraigRinger thank you for your reminder, I couldn't install psycopg2 because I downloaded 32-bit version installer. 64-bit version is be installed successfully with x64 python 2.7.6!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Install the binary distribution of psycopg2 for the same architecture as your Python version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg).

Your Psycopg2 architecture must match the architecture of the Python binary you installed. So if you have a 32-bit Python 2.7 you must get the 32-bit psycopg2; if you have the 64-bit Python 2.7, you must get the 64-bit pycopg2.

This applies to any Python module that contains binary modules, not just psycopg2.