# Error compile with python psycopg2

Tags: psycopg2

I installed psycopg2 following  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173362/6083334) answer but when I compile this code

```
import psycopg2
import pprint
import sys`
```

I get this error:

```
c:\code_python\tutorial>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
import psycopg2
File "C:\Python27.10\lib\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicaci¾n Win32 vßlida.
```

What is the problem with psycopg2?

Comment: Sorry but where is your codes ?

Comment: It is only import for
verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my question, the problem is i try install psycopg2 x86, when i install python x64  for my computer. I download  psycopg2 x64 and all fine